# REST calls in Android studio (post 2014 - IntelliJ based)

Tags: android, rest, android-studio

There are plug-ins for Eclipse, where we can see the REST conversation logs.

In the new Android Studio, based on IntelliJ, is there a way to see the outgoing calls (`POST/GET`) from the app?

If i can capture them, I am hoping to be able to make similar calls using the [postman rest client.](https://www.getpostman.com/features)

Comment: Please describe your expectations by feature.

Comment: thanks! added some more detail

Comment: what httpclient r u using? 'httpclient logging' in googl should get u started. Most of the clients have Docs on verbose logging that cover all kinds of debug related issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TunnelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=155) plugin. But looks like it's old.

If your are Windows user then I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff traffic. See [more details](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2014/06/sniffing-http-traffic-on-an-android-device.html)